# Handling android back button

Tags: android, event-handling, back-button, back-button-control

I have a basic question about android development. In my app i have a autocomplete box. When user click on a menu button, autocomplete become visible. When user clicks on an entry in autocomplete, the text views show it. I want to use back button such that when user presses it . Textview become invisible , on again click autocomplte disappears and than on third click app exits. But in my app on a single click app exits. I am a new to development so doesn't know much about it, so i ask here.

Comment: Technically, @ZouZou points in the right direction. But I would think twice before introducing a UI behaviour which is unique to a single app.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
   public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
       if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
         //stuff
       }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
   }
```

Since API 5 :

```
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        //stuff

    }
```